# Who started it? And who did not?

Tags: pattern, visual, sequence

### The question is: Who started it? And who did not?

---

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]
[image: pic4]
[image: pic5]
[image: pic6]
[image: pic7]
[image: pic8]
[image: pic9]
[image: pic10]
[image: pic11]
[image: pic12]

Comment: Is there significance to China's flag having six-pointed stars instead of its usual five-pointed stars?

Comment: Is there a reason the answer hasn't been accepted?

Answer (score 8):

Filling in the blanks we have

- > Doris Day
- > Joe DiMaggio
- > Richard Nixon

As to who started it:

> It was always burning, since the world was turning. So certainly not started by us.

And to spell it out explicitly

> The sequence of images is enumerated in the lyrics of the popular Billy Joel song, "We didn't start the fire." The lyrics also explicitly say who started it (no one, it was always burning) and who didn't (we didn't) http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/billyjoel/wedidntstartthefire.html

Comment: Is it just not being a USA-an that leaves me as confused by the answer as I was by the question? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This seems like an incomplete answer.  As @Penguino noted above, while this answer contains the response to the question as stated, it doesn't sufficiently explain the meaning of the question, and how the answer was derived.  I would appreciate a more-fleshed-out answer that allows anyone reading it to understand both the question and the answer.  (Remember that the ultimate goal of Stack Exchange is to become a repository of questions and answers.  Help those encountering this puzzle in the future by explaining your answer sufficiently.)

Comment: Added some more info to make the solution more explicit.